# I can not connect with sockets using IP WLAN

Tags: sockets

I'm trying to make a connection by sockets, but I can not connect when I'm using IP WLAN, but the lookback IP connects and works, as seen in the two photos below

[image: connection working with IP loopback]

[image: connection working with IP loopback]

That's what happens when trying to connect through the WLAN IP:

[image]

The setup below is my local IP.

[image]

I think I need to do some setting on my router but not sure what. I have a DIR-610 router, in which several devices are connected.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the problem is that port 6001 is being blocked somewhere, probably your router?

Another issue might be Windows itself blocking port 6001 from leaving the computer. Can you put another computer on the same internal network (192.168.0.x) that can listen for the connection?

If you have any programming skills, either Node.JS or Python are good tools for creating mini servers capable of listening for websockets. Node in particular has all the libraries you need.

Comment: I try with other machine and works.
I will try to the Internet from my college, I understand there is a door just for that. Thanks for the tip

Comment: It should be easy enough to create a router through the firewall of your router.